# TextWatcher crash when get edittext

Tags: java, android

After I type, it gives me the message: your app isn`t responding.
do you want to close it?
WAIT   OK

I think because of the `edt_search.gettext().tostring()` inside the `setData()`

```
 private void setupViews() {
edt_search = findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
progress.hide();

edt_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editable.length() != 0) {
      setData();
    }
  }
});
}



private void setData() {
AndroidNetworking.post("uri")
  .addBodyParameter("word", edt_search.getText().toString())
  .build()
  .getAsObjectList(Search.class, new ParsedRequestListener<List<Search>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(List<Search> searches) {
      for (Search search : searches) {
        searchList.add(search);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
      loading(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ANError anError) {
      Log.e("android-networking", "error: " + anError.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Check your logs in android studio and post the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably guessing it right. By empiric experience, I found out it's problematic to call methods from EditText inside `afterTextChanged` method (at least without removing the text watcher first). If possible, it's much better to use the Editable object that is passed as an argument. So, in your case, you could try two approaches:

First (easiest and which I most recommend in this specific case): Pass your string to the method setData(), so you don't need to access your EditText in this method:

```
....

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (editable.length() != 0) {
            setData(editable.toString());
        }
    }

....

private void setData(String searchString) {
AndroidNetworking.post("http://akhbaresteghlal.ir/search/getInformations.php")
  .addBodyParameter("word", searchString)
  .build()
....
```

Second option (if, by any reason, you absolutely need to access your editText directly): Remove the TextWatcher before calling setData() (and any method from EditText) and then add it again after.

```
....

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (editable.length() != 0) {
            edt_search.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            setData();
            edt_search.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }

....

private void setData() {
    AndroidNetworking.post("http://akhbaresteghlal.ir/search/getInformations.php")
      .addBodyParameter("word", edt_search.getText().toString())
      .build()
    ....
```

Hope it helps!